# the program arm-linux-androideabi-gcc is currently not installed

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to compile FFTW for android using NDK r10.
Using the instructions here: 
http://blog.jimjh.com/compiling-open-source-libraries-with-android-ndk-part-2.html

However, when I run ./configure it fails because of the error: the program arm-linux-androideabi-gcc is currently not installed.
I validate that my PATH includes the needed entries - and of course the file arm-linux-androideabi-gcc exists in the bin folder.

can you please help me

```
#!/bin/sh
# FourierTest/build.sh
# Compiles fftw3 for Android
# Make sure you have NDK_ROOT defined in .bashrc or .bash_profile

INSTALL_DIR="`pwd`/jni/analysis/fftw3"
SRC_DIR="`pwd`/../fftw-3.3.4"
NDK_ROOT="~/utils/android-ndk-r10"

cd $SRC_DIR

export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT="~/utils/android-ndk-r10"
export ANDROID_NDK_TOOLCHAIN="~/utils/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/"

export PATH="~/utils/android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/:$PATH"
export SYS_ROOT="~/utils/android-ndk-r10/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/"
export CC="arm-linux-androideabi1-gcc --sysroot=$SYS_ROOT"
export LD="arm-linux-androideabi-ld"
export AR="arm-linux-androideabi-ar"
export RANLIB="arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib"
export STRIP="arm-linux-androideabi-strip"

mkdir -p $INSTALL_DIR
./configure --prefix=$INSTALL_DIR --enable-float

make
make install

exit 0
```

Edit: I had small issue with my path before because of me playing with it. Now it gives me:
"Gcc error: gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory"

Comment: Please post your modified script

Comment: What does `--enable-float` do? Can you run configure's help, and paste the text? (There's lots of devils in the details when it comes to floating point handling).

Answer (score 2):

Open the configure file and make sure the path referenced to arm-linux-androideabi toolchain is the same as the path in which your toolchain is present. Also set the following variables

- ANDROID_NDK_ROOT
- ANDROID_NDK_TOOLCHAIN

to point to the right folders.

Comment: Thanks. But adding the variables did not help. the error is raised by lib-tool - i can't find the path there. I have added my build script

Comment: Set the variables outside your script file on the command line. Then execute the ./configure command.

Comment: I have edited my error. now receiving gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory. that did not solve my new issue.

Comment: @G3M - Why does `ANDROID_NDK_TOOLCHAIN` need to be set? Is it specific to FFTW? (And I'm aware of the requirement for `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT` and `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`).